# Updating a Single Object Field in Django View

Tags: python, django, django-views

**Edited:** I am trying to update the value of a single field inside one of Django's objects. Here is the code:

```
class TodoCompleteView(generic.DetailView):        
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        # Call the superclass
        object = super(TodoCompleteView, self).get_object()
        # Record the last accessed date
        object.todo_completed = True
        object.save()
        # Return the object
        return object
```

However, I keep getting an error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /8/complete
>   list/todo_detail.html

How can avoid this? I simply want this view to flip a certain value in DB.

Comment: Have you migrated your database?

Comment: Yes. I have also just checked again. No changes.

Comment: I don't see why `objects` can be `NoneType`. Can you show us full stack trace?

Comment: Please show the whole context of this code. Why are you trying to call update within get_queryset?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am just trying to update a field. I tried doing it outside the get_queryset but it would not work either.

Answer (score 2):

You inherit view from [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) class, which by default is to view some models and not to change. Also, apparently, you use `GET` request to change the data. This is the wrong approach.

Alternatively I advise you to try to make inherit your view from [SingleObjectMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#singleobjectmixin) and [View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#view) and manually create a handler for `POST` request.

I would rewrite your example like this:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin

class TodoCompleteView(SingleObjectMixin, View):
    model = Todo

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.todo_completed = True
        self.object.save(update_fields=('todo_completed', ))
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

P.S. you get the error, because `DetailView` subclassed from [SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#singleobjecttemplateresponsemixin) which tries to render the template called `<model_name>_detail.html`.